# Making polynomial irreducible by adding term of given arithmetic progression

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, arithmetic-progressions

Given a polynomial $p(n)$ and natural numbers $m$ and $r$, is there always a natural number $q$ such that $p'(n) = p(n) + qm + r$ is irreducible? I mean polynomials irreducible over the integers.